# Extracting image value along circle of an image

Tags: plotting, image-processing

I want to extract the `ImageValue` (along  yellow circle) of an given below [image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/s3mlbfrbrrp8lvg/image.jpg?dl=0)

[image: images]
I try with the below code to find the `ImageValue` along the line, but I want to extract and plot the `ImageValue` along the yellow circle.

```
        With[{img = image}, 
        Manipulate[
        ListLinePlot[ImageValue[img, {All, row}], 
       PlotRange -> {{100, 350}, {0.1, .71}}], {row, 207, 500 - 0.5, 1}]]
```

Comment: [`Interpolation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interpolation.html) together with a parametrization of the circle & [`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html) should work

Comment: @Mathe, I am new in Mathematica, Please explore your idea.

Comment: Try to read the documentation pages for the linked symbols, they are very instructive on how to use the functions. The rest is just Maths. Here is something to get you started: `Table[Interpolation[data][r {Cos[ϕ]r, Sin[ϕ]}], {ϕ, 0, 2π, π/10}]`, where `data` is the data you used for the plot, and `r` is the radius of the circle

Comment: @praksh Your question lacks important details that are needed to give an answer. If you ask for the intensity profile of **the given image** along the yellow circle, then the answer is simple: You have constantly yellow. I'm sure this is not what you want. Please provide example code and edit your question. Additionally, Mathe172 basically answered how you can achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: @halirutan, I have uploaded the image and code that i am using, I am able to extract and plot the imagevale along the diagonal. How to extract the imagevale along the line using Mathe172 code ?

Comment: How is the image generated? Your code does not allow to reproduce it, so the only answer you can get is what halirutan said: the `ImageValue` along a yellow circle is constantly yellow.

Comment: OK, it is still not a great question, as I'm still unsure what you really want. If you extract the image-data exactly along the yellow line, you will get a constantly yellow color or (since you turned it into a gray image) a constant gray value. I would guess you are interested in the values along a circle that is placed in the symmetry-center of the underlying data, but again, I'm not sure. Question: Do you have only the *image* or do you have also the *data* that was used in the density plot?

Comment: @halirutan, I have image from camera.

Answer (score 5):

Here is my go on the question. You need to import the image and then use `ImageData` to get the pixel matrix. When you want to plot a column or row of the image only, you can simply extract a column or row of the pixel matrix. A circle is a bit different because you don't hit exact pixel positions on your way along the circular path.

That is the reason you need to interpolate the data. Another good thing with interpolation is that you can specify the range of your data. If you use `{{-1,1},{-1,1}}` then your interpolated data will have the center of your image directly at `{0,0}`. The parametric formula for a circle around `{0,0}` with radius `r` is

$$ \{r\cdot\cos\phi, r\cdot\sin\phi\}$$

and this is what we will use to extract the data along the circular path. Here is a simple demonstration:

```
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[r*{Cos[phi], Sin[phi]}, {phi, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}],
 {r, 0.01, 1}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you interpolate your data like I will do, `r` can range from $0<r<=1$. Here we go:

```
img = ColorConvert[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RpmA.jpg"], "Grayscale"];
data = ImageData[img];
ip = ListInterpolation[data, {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}];
```

The next function will give you `n` data-points along the circle with radius `r`

```
circleData[r_, n_Integer] := Table[ip @@ (r*{Cos[phi], Sin[phi]}),
  {phi, 0., 2 Pi, 2 Pi/(n - 1)}];
```

Quick check if everything works

```
Manipulate[
 ListLinePlot[circleData[r, 200], PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 1}}],
 {r, .01, 1}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It seems `r=0.293` is about the radius where your circle goes directly through the smaller gray spots that are in the brighter spots. To get the 512 sampling points along this circle you can therefore use

```
cData = circleData[0.293, 512];
ListPlot[cData]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

## Edit

> How to combine ParametricPlot of circle for given r and image? Show[circle,image] is not working.

An easy (but not so fast) way is to directly use the interpolation function `ip`

```
Show[
 DensityPlot[ip[x, y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
  ColorFunction -> GrayLevel, PlotPoints -> ImageDimensions[img], 
  MaxRecursion -> 0],
 ParametricPlot[.293*{Cos[phi], Sin[phi]}, {phi, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Red}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks very much @halirutan

Comment: How to combine ParametricPlot of circle for given r and image? Show[circle,image] is not working.

Comment: Please see the edit at the end of my answer.

Answer (score 3):

This would be one way to do it.

1. Take the image.

   `img = Import["image_preview.jpeg"]`

[image]

2. Create a new image of same size with circle.

   `cen = ImageDimensions[img]/2; rad = 80;
   img1 = Rasterize[Show[img, Epilog -> {Yellow, Thick, Circle[cen, rad]}]]`

[image]

3. Locate coordinate for yellow dots and find the `ImageValue`.

`d = 0.01;
 pts = PixelValuePositions[img1, Yellow, d];
 npts = Length[pts]
 cols = ImageValue[img, #] & /@ pts;
 Graphics[{RGBColor[cols[[#]]], Point[pts[[#]]]} & /@ Range[npts], 
  PlotRange -> {{0, ImageDimensions[img][[1]]}, {0, ImageDimensions[img][[2]]}},
  Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> None]`

[image]

Increasing `d` will increase the number of points. This would work for any arbitrary line and colour.

**For Grayscale**

```
img = ColorConvert[img, "Grayscale"];
cen = ImageDimensions[img]/2; rad = 80;
img1 = Rasterize[Show[img, Epilog -> {Yellow, Thick, Circle[cen, rad]}]]

d = 0.01;
pts = PixelValuePositions[img1, Yellow, d];
npts = Length[pts]
cols = ImageValue[img, #] & /@ pts;
Graphics[{GrayLevel[cols[[#]]], Point[pts[[#]]]} & /@ Range[npts], 
 PlotRange -> {{0, ImageDimensions[img][[1]]}, {0,ImageDimensions[img][[2]]}},
 Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> None]

data=Join[pts[[#]], {cols[[#]]}] & /@ Range[npts];
ListPointPlot3D[data]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks@ sumit, As you can see intensity or pixel value in not constant each points on the circle, How to plot according to their pixel value just like in line profile.

Comment: You can increase `d`, then it will pick both yellow and yellowish points. The 3d point plot I get looks similar to yours. So increasing `d` you may get what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CirclePoints[center, r, n]` to get `n` points along a circle around `center` with radius `r`, and then `ImageValue[img, circlePoints]` to get the interpolated image value at these points. This returns a list of RGB values for each pixel. Use `[[All,1]]` to show only the Red channel:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3mo6.png"]

center = ImageDimensions[img]/2;
r = 100;

circlePoints = CirclePoints[center, r, 360];
rgb = ImageValue[img, circlePoints];
red = rgb[[All, 1]];

Row[{
  Show[img, Graphics[{Yellow, Line[circlePts]}]],
  ListLinePlot[red, ImageSize -> 500]
  }]
```

[image]

`ImageValue` is quite fast, so you can even use this dynamically:

```
Row[{
  VerticalSlider[Dynamic[r], {0, 200}],
  LocatorPane[Dynamic[center], 
   Dynamic[Show[img, Graphics[{Yellow, Circle[center, r]}]]]],
  Dynamic[
   ListLinePlot[
    ImageValue[img, CirclePoints[center, r, 360]][[All, 1]], 
    ImageSize -> 500]]
  }]
```

Here you can change the radius and center and see the change in real time:

[image]